# executing independent for loop with each condition in java

Tags: java

I am stuck up in an issue that is I have the below piece of code in which i read the multiple excel tab sheets and store the sheets value in an object named brokerInvoice object

this was working fine if i have single tab excel sheet as shown below that is finally it reads that single excel sheet  sheet and do some manipulation and finally set the object brokerInvoice

```
 List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> brokerInvoiceLineItemList = new ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem>();
               brokerInvoice = readinginvoiceimpl.findHeaderRowNumber(workbookXls, 0, brokerInvoiceLineItemList, brokerInvoice , brokerIdLong , finalfilteredfilename,dateType );
```

The issue come when i have to read the excel sheet with multiple tabs  for which below you can see i have started the loop but the issue comes as soon it reads the first sheet it sets the value of the object  named brokerInvoice and then it go for the second excel sheet manipulation and override the first stored object properties value so the object named brokerInvoice is always populated witht the value of the last sheet

please advise how can i correct my below loop so that for every sheet manipulation is alo done and the broker invoice should contain the value of all the tabs

```
  for (int i = 0; i < workbookXls.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> brokerInvoiceLineItemList = new ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem>();
                brokerInvoice = readinginvoiceimpl.findHeaderRowNumber(workbookXls, 0, brokerInvoiceLineItemList, brokerInvoice , brokerIdLong , finalfilteredfilename,dateType );
                }
```

Comment: For a start, you're recreating `brokerInvoiceLineItemList` every time through the loop...then trampling on it every time, so even moving the declaration outside of the loop wouldn't address the core issue.

Answer (score 1):

If `brokerInvoice` is an object of `BrokerInvoice`. Then you need to add that object to the `brokerInvoiceList`. Finally this list will contain all the tab objects:

```
    List<BrokerInvoice> brokerInvoiceList = new ArrayList<BrokerInvoice>();
        for (int i = 0; i < workbookXls.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
           List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> brokerInvoiceLineItemList = new ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem>();                  
brokerInvoice = readinginvoiceimpl.findHeaderRowNumber(workbookXls, 0, brokerInvoiceLineItemList, brokerInvoice , brokerIdLong , finalfilteredfilename,dateType );
                             brokerInvoiceList.add(brokerInvoice );
                            }
```

Comment: No Ravi just to clear please brokerinvoicelineitem is an list inside the broker invoice object that is broker invoice is an pojo in which brokerinvoiceline item is an list type

Comment: Sometimes answering from a phone makes you miss some important details, as happened to me. In updating the above answer!

Comment: It's OK usually happens with developers anyhow please advise how to overcome from the above mentioned problem

Comment: Updated my answer above, if it is still not fulfilling your requirement, then please let me know all your object types and the utilities you are using above.